# How to remove styles from a textmate scope in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

How can I remove the styles set on a textmate scope by a theme?  The theme I am using sets a font weight on the `storage.type.function` scope, and I want to remove it so that it inherits from a parent scope.

Both keywords have the most specific scope as `storage.type.function`, which is set to bold by the theme.

I have used the two less-specific scopes `meta.function` and `meta.function.closure` to set regular and bold styles, however both these are overridden by the more specific `storage.type.function` scope set by the theme.

Thus to get my custom style to apply, I need to somehow remove the style set on `storage.type.function` so it falls back to the `meta` values I have set.  Setting it to blank doesn't work:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            // Want to unset this style
            { "scope": "storage.type.function", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },

            // Neither of these apply because the one above overrides them
            { "scope": "meta.function",         "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "meta.function.closure", "settings": { "fontStyle": "bold" } },
    ]
}
```

How can I unset `storage.type.function` so that the `meta` styles apply?

Here is some test PHP to reproduce the issue, save it as `example.php` and open it in VSCode:

```
<?php

class Test {
  function a() {           // "function" should not be bold (meta.function)
    $b = function () {};   // "function" should be bold (meta.function.closure)
  }
}
```